# Generated flow import error: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Accidentally found an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.assignedNodes is not a function generated-flow-imports.d69a29a8.js:465:120
    getFlattenedNodes https://host/legal/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports.d69a29a8.js:465
    flush https://host/legal/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports.d69a29a8.js:465
    _schedule https://host/legal/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports.d69a29a8.js:465
    wp https://host/legal/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports.d69a29a8.js:321
Caused by: undefined
```

Latest Vaadin(23.3.4) production mode, Chrome(109.0.5414.75), Firefox(109.0)

No visual errors.

How critical is this?

Comment: I doubt anyone can tell you how critical it is to your application. Also, Vaadin appears to be Java/Typescript based, is the Javascript tag intentional?

Comment: No, i will remove javascript tag